# Trying to add OxyPlot to a Xamarin Forms xaml Page

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Im trying to include oxyplot into a Xamarin.Forms-Project

This is my Xaml.cs file where Im building the PlotModel.

```
private void GeneratePlot()
    {
        var Points = new List<DataPoint>
        {
            new DataPoint(0, 0),
            new DataPoint(10, 5),
            new DataPoint(20, 10),
            new DataPoint(30, 16),
            new DataPoint(40, 12),
            new DataPoint(50, 19)
        };
        var Points2 = new List<DataPoint>
        {
            new DataPoint(0, 0),
            new DataPoint(10, 7),
            new DataPoint(20, 8),
            new DataPoint(30, 8),
            new DataPoint(40, 20),
            new DataPoint(50, 25)
        };
        var m = new PlotModel();
        m.PlotType = PlotType.XY;
        m.InvalidatePlot(true);
        m.Title = "hello oxy";
        m.ResetAllAxes();
        var ls1 = new LineSeries();
        var ls2 = new LineSeries();
        ls1.ItemsSource = Points;
        ls2.ItemsSource = Points2;

        m.Series.Add(ls1);
        m.Series.Add(ls2);
        var _opv = new OxyPlotView
        {
            WidthRequest = 300,
            HeightRequest = 300,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua
        };
        _opv.Model = m;
        PlModel = m;
    }
```

In Code this works fine when I just put the OxyPlotModel _opy into a StackLayout.
But when Im going to add it into Xaml like this:

```
 <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Im getting the following Exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for OxyPlot.XamarinForms.PlotView ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty.Create'.
```

Does anyone know what I can do to use OxyPlot with Xaml?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version of OxyPlot you have is compatible with the version of Forms you have.

I've had to manually download the OxyPlot source and update the Xamarin.Forms NuGet in the past.

Comment: How can I found out whether they are compatible or not?

Comment: The NuGet package usually says which version its compatible with in the description.  Which version of Forms are you on?  Which version of Oxy?

Comment: Hi, in my References Xamarin.Forms.Core and Xamarin.Forms.Xaml is 1.4 Xamarin.Forms.Platform is 1.0. OxyPlot and OxyPlot.XamarinForms is 2014.1.517.0